# can you identify a show about a man thawed from cryosleep to help future survivors of mankind?

Tags: story-identification, tv, suspended-animation

This is driving me crazy. I think it was a short lived TV series, maybe scifi channel. Not real recent but within the last 10 years I think. The back story was a near future that had perfected cryosleep but it was expensive. Thousands of the rich put themselves to sleep during troubled times, expecting a better future, longer life, diseases cured, etc.

The series begins with one man awaken to a world with a handful of survivors of an alien invasion who are isolated on ocean platforms protecting the sleeping remainder of mankind while fending off the encroachment of aliens of some amorphous form who are learning how to cross the ocean on storms (or something like that). He is a replacement for a survivor who died, because there are resources for a specific number of workers, all needed to keep things going. He's an outsider, trying to prove himself worthy while earning the trust of his partner, a women who was close to the man who died, even though feelings are a luxury this bleak future can hardly afford.

Does any of this sound like something you've seen? I think it only lasted a few episodes.

Additional details: could have been a single shot tv movie, possibly a pilot for a show never produced. Definitely TV though, low budget effects, not a cast I can name. Some stock images of ocean platforms at sea in different kinds of weather, spare industrial interiors, one helicopter to move people around for maintenance weather permitting, seen only in closeup. Alien menace was just a dark stain under stormy water shots. One "episode" was our protagonist isolated/stranded on a maintenance shift on a remote platform due to weather, gutting it out, nearly dying from effort and exposure but it helps prove him in the eyes of the others. Your tools are critical...you must never lose your tools or something bad will happen.

Comment: I recall a sort story like this sometime in the past few years in either Asimov's or F&SF.  I don't recall any TV series like this though.  Can you recall any production or broadcast details, such as any actors, or what channel it was on?

Comment: Language might be nice as well. I am up on most English-speaking sci-fi TV and this does not seem familiar at all.

Comment: It is in English. I'm a pretty good googler and have scanned many many lists of short-lived scifi shows and pilots and tv movies and I find nothing close.  Im doubting my own memory except what I do remember seems rather clear and hardly something I would create from nothing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I'm pretty sure I've read the same story. I could have sworn it was in one of the "year's best SF" anthologies, and that it was by a fairly well-known author, but now I can't find it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds suspiciously similar to the short story "Sleepover" by Alastair Reynolds. Maybe it was an adaptation?

**The back story was a near future that had perfected cryosleep but it was expensive. Thousands of the rich put themselves to sleep during troubled times, expecting a better future, longer life, diseases cured, etc.**

> "He was one of the first two hundred thousand," Clausen said. "The ultimate exclusive club." [...]
>
> "You remember why you went under, of course," Clausen said.
>
> "Because I could," Gaunt said. "Because anyone in my position would have done the same. The world was getting better, it was coming out of the trough. But it wasn't there yet. And the doctors kept telling us that the immortality breakthrough was just around the corner, year after year." [...]

**The series begins with one man awaken to a world with a handful of survivors of an alien invasion who are isolated on ocean platforms protecting the sleeping remainder of mankind while fending off the encroachment of aliens of some amorphous form who are learning how to cross the ocean on storms (or something like that).**

> "Maybe it would help if I told you that the current population of the Earth is also two billion, near as it matters," Clausen said. "Almost everyone's asleep. There's just a handful of us still awake, playing caretaker, watching over the rigs and OTEC plants."

**He is a replacement for a survivor who died, because there are resources for a specific number of workers, all needed to keep things going.**

> "Where are we going?"
>
> "Running a shift change," Da Silva said, wrapping a pair of earphones around his skull. "Couple of days ago there was an accident out on J platform. Lost Gimenez, and Nero's been hurt. Weather was too bad to do the extraction until today, but now we have our window. Reason we thawed you, actually. I'm taking over from Gimenez, so you have to cover for me here."
>
> "You have a labour shortage, so you brought me out of hibernation?"
>
> "That about covers it," Da Silva said.

**He's an outsider, trying to prove himself worthy while earning the trust of his partner, a women who was close to the man who died, even though feelings are a luxury this bleak future can hardly afford.**

> "It hasn't been easy for her. She lost someone not too long ago." Nero seemed to hesitate. "There was an accident. They're pretty common out here, with the kind of work we do. But when Paulo died we didn't even have a body to put back in the box. He fell into the sea, last we ever saw of him. [...] If Paolo hadn't died, then we wouldn't have to pull Gimenez out of storage. And if Gimenez hadn't died... well, you get the picture. You can't help it, but you're filling the space Paolo used to occupy. And you're not Paolo."

**Alien menace was just a dark stain under stormy water shots.**

> It took Gaunt a few moments to make out what Nero had already seen. Half-way to the limit of vision, part of the sea appeared to be lit from below, a smudge of sickly yellow-green against the grey and white everywhere else. A vision came to mind, half-remembered from some stiff-backed picture book he had once owned as a child, of a luminous, fabulously spired aquatic palace pushing up from the depths, barnacled in light, garlanded by mermaids and shoals of jewel-like fish. But there was, he sensed, nothing remotely magical or enchanted about what was happening under that yellow-green smear. It was something that had Clausen and Nero rattled, and they wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the short story I remember too.

Comment: Thank you thank you! Sleepover was in the recent anthology "Robot Uprisings", ed Daniel H. Wilson and John Joseph Adams which I read, I am embarrassed to say, less than a year ago. A strong story that my mind turned into a barely remembered non-existent TV show. Maybe I had a dream about it after reading it or something, because the visual memory is still strong, even though I forgot it was a strange extra-dimensional AI turning on us, not alien invasion. Thanks again. What a great site this is!